# How do I delete application sync data permanently?

Tags: applications, google

Is there a way I can completely remove sync data for an app and thus prevent it from syncing with my google account? For example, I had Google Fit on my other mobile, I wasn't using it at all, but it is still listed in my account to sync on this new phone, even when I dont have Google Fit. Is there a way I could completely remove its association with my devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just go to google settings, delete all your Google Fit history and other App-data, remove google fit, and not worry about it showing up under your account sync settings.